# Why do my api calls not work in nginx but work fine locally?

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, mern

I am trying to deploy my MERN stack application to a server using AWS-EC2. Though everything seems to be working when I try and make API calls I get weird non-json returns which destroys all functionality.

I think I read that the reason this may be happening is that Nginx doesn't work with static pages, but when I tried using the non-static page (client/public/index.html as opposed to client/build/index.html), the page just renders black, and the inspecting element shows there is nothing in the body.

Is there any workaround or alternative solution?

Here is what the API returns using the server port created with Nginx:
[image: nginx]

Here is it working perfectly fine locally on my machine:

[image: here]